# Can macro perform compound assignments

Tags: c

I read little [gnu online docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation) about macro and little confused about this sentence:

> Also multi-character operators such as += can be formed by token pasting

So I wander if macro can perform compound assignments,How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define PASTE(a,b) a##b
int foo;
foo PASTE(+,=) 2;
```

The only time I've ever seen this be *useful* was in the inner loop of a bytecode interpreter, which tends to look like a gigantic case statement with very repetitive code in each arm:

```
case OP_add: {
    if (sp < 2) goto underflow;
    double x = stack[--sp];
    stack[sp-1] += x;
} break;
```

Repeat for each supported binary arithmetic operator.  With the ability to token-paste, you can generate them all from a macro:

```
#define ARITH_BINOP(name, oper) case OP_##name: { \
    if (sp < 2) goto underflow; \
    double x = stack[--sp]; \
    stack[sp-1] oper##= x; \
} break /* deliberate absence of semicolon */
```

and then, in the switch, you can just write

```
ARITH_BINOP(add, +);
ARITH_BINOP(sub, -);
ARITH_BINOP(mul, *);
/* etc */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, documentation says about cases like:

```
#define COMPST(x, y) x ## y

int 
foo(int x)
{
  return x COMPST(+, =) 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course macros can perform anything you can achieve in C code:

```
#define INCREMENT(x) ((x) += 1)

main() {
   int n=42;
   INCREMENT(n);
}
```

the line you read means another thing which I suspect you are not interested in...